# Calculate next working day

Tags: c#, datetime

I have tried to tackle this question as follows:

> ```
> The program Calculates the next Working day, taking into account:  
>    - weekends (Saturdays and Sundays)  
>    - holidays happening in the middle of the week 
>
> param name="OrderDate" the date on which the order is placed
> param name="workingDays" the number of workingdays to process the order      
> returns the date on which the Order is Requested to Ship
> ```

```
    public static DateTime getNextWorkingDay(DateTime OrderDate, int workingDays)
    {
        DateTime Holiday = new DateTime();
        List<DateTime> SelectedHolidays = new List<DateTime>();
        List<HolidayList> HolidayList = new List<HolidayList>();

        int calculatedWorkingDays=0;
        if (workingDays <= 5)
            calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays;
        else if (workingDays % 6 == 0)
        {
            calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays + workingDays / 6 * 2;
        }
        else
        {
            calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays + workingDays / 7 * 2;
        }



        HolidayList =  "Read the list from Json file";

        foreach (var holiday in HolidayList)
        {
            string year = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();
            Holiday = DateTime.Parse(holiday.MonthAndDayValue + "-" + year);

            if (Holiday.Day == 1 && Holiday.Month == 1)
            {
                year = (DateTime.Today.Year + 1).ToString();
                Holiday = DateTime.Parse(holiday.MonthAndDayValue + "-" + year);
            }


            SelectedHolidays.Add(Holiday.Date);

            if (Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                if (Holiday.Date == OrderDate.Date)
                    OrderDate.AddDays(1);
                if (Holiday.Date > OrderDate.Date)
                {
                    int K = (int)(Holiday.Date - OrderDate.Date).TotalDays;
                    if (K <= calculatedWorkingDays)
                    {
                        calculatedWorkingDays++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (OrderDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            calculatedWorkingDays++;
        }
        else if (OrderDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || OrderDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        {
            calculatedWorkingDays += 2;
        }

        // this is required date 
        DateTime date_OrderRequestedToShip = OrderDate.AddDays(calculatedWorkingDays);

        //check if the last date fall on a non working day(holiday  or weekend)
        calculatedWorkingDays = 0;
        foreach (DateTime d in SelectedHolidays)
            if (d.Date == date_OrderRequestedToShip.Date)
                calculatedWorkingDays++;
        date_OrderRequestedToShip = date_OrderRequestedToShip.AddDays(calculatedWorkingDays);
        if (date_OrderRequestedToShip.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            calculatedWorkingDays = 1;
        }
        else if (date_OrderRequestedToShip.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            calculatedWorkingDays = 2;
        }

        return date_OrderRequestedToShip.AddDays(calculatedWorkingDays);
    }
```

The holiday list contains the month and day (MM/dd) part only with out the year part:

```
{
    "holidayName": "Memorial Day",
    "MonthAndDayValue": "05-30"
}
```

Can anyone help to tune up or suggest changes to make the code more efficient?

Comment: Does it work though? If I enter 2015-03-13 as orderdate with 3 working days and I use the 15th, 16th and 17th as holidays it tells me that the 18th is the next working day. But then I've only got the 14th as a tru

Answer (score 7):

First, you should separate a process of parsing your input from your business logic. So, your first step is to convert your holidays input to a structure you'll be working with. So, let's say you have a `List<Holiday>` where

```
public struct Holiday
{
    public readonly int Month;
    public readonly int Day;

    public Holiday(int month, int day)
    {
        Month = month;
        Day = day;
    }
}
```

Now, in your place I'd start with implementation of something that enumerates working days like so:

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetWorkingDays(DateTime startDate, List<Holiday> holidays)
{
    var date = startDate;

    for (;;date = date.AddDays(1))
    {        
        if (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
            date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday &&
            holidays.All(holiday => holiday.Day != date.Day ||
                                    holiday.Month != date.Month))
        {
            yield return date;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this iterator is endless, so you should be cautious enumerating it.

Now, your problem can be solved with just one line

```
var result = GetWorkingDays(orderDate, holidays).Skip(workingDays).First();
```

Complete example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W3dalr

Answer (score 4):

Your method does too much and that makes it hard to follow/optimize.

This should be extracted into its own method.

> ```
>     int calculatedWorkingDays=0;
>     if (workingDays <= 5)
>         calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays;
>     else if (workingDays % 6 == 0)
>     {
>         calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays + workingDays / 6 * 2;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays + workingDays / 7 * 2;
>     }
> ```

Then this block

> ```
>     HolidayList =  "Read the list from Json file";
>
>     foreach (var holiday in HolidayList)
>     {
>         string year = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();
>         Holiday = DateTime.Parse(holiday.MonthAndDayValue + "-" + year);
>
>         if (Holiday.Day == 1 && Holiday.Month == 1)
>         {
>             year = (DateTime.Today.Year + 1).ToString();
>             Holiday = DateTime.Parse(holiday.MonthAndDayValue + "-" + year);
>         }
>
>
>         SelectedHolidays.Add(Holiday.Date);
>
>         if (Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
>         {
>             //do nothing
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             if (Holiday.Date == OrderDate.Date)
>                 OrderDate.AddDays(1);
>             if (Holiday.Date > OrderDate.Date)
>             {
>                 int K = (int)(Holiday.Date - OrderDate.Date).TotalDays;
>                 if (K <= calculatedWorkingDays)
>                 {
>                     calculatedWorkingDays++;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

You actually might want to split that into several methods.

Also, watch your white space. There's never a need for more than a single blank line.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can improve.  First, never have empty `if` statements:

```
if (Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    //do nothing
}
else
{
    if (Holiday.Date == OrderDate.Date)
        OrderDate.AddDays(1);
    if (Holiday.Date > OrderDate.Date)
    {
        int K = (int)(Holiday.Date - OrderDate.Date).TotalDays;
        if (K <= calculatedWorkingDays)
        {
            calculatedWorkingDays++;
        }
    }
}
```

Reverse the conditional and get rid of the else:

```
if (Holiday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && Holiday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    if (Holiday.Date == OrderDate.Date)
        OrderDate.AddDays(1);
    if (Holiday.Date > OrderDate.Date)
    {
        int K = (int)(Holiday.Date - OrderDate.Date).TotalDays;
        if (K <= calculatedWorkingDays)
        {
            calculatedWorkingDays++;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, keep your style similar.  In the above, you have a `if` statement with one line without braces, and another with braces.  You should always choose one style, preferably braces, and stick to it; the same applies to loops:

```
foreach (DateTime d in SelectedHolidays)
        if (d.Date == date_OrderRequestedToShip.Date)
            calculatedWorkingDays++;
```

Use this instead:

```
foreach (DateTime d in SelectedHolidays)
{
    if (d.Date == date_OrderRequestedToShip.Date)
    {
        calculatedWorkingDays++;
    }
}
```

Right here, you only use the variable `K` once:

```
int K = (int)(Holiday.Date - OrderDate.Date).TotalDays;
if (K <= calculatedWorkingDays)
{
    calculatedWorkingDays++;
}
```

Not only is this a bad and undescriptive name for a variable, it is unnecessary.  Also, what type does the `.TotalDays` return, a `double`?  If so, you probably do not need to cast it to an `int`.

```
if ((Holiday.Date - OrderDate.Date).TotalDays <= calculatedWorkingDays)
{
    calculatedWorkingDays++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just some points:

```
    if (workingDays <= 5)
        calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays;
    else if (workingDays % 6 == 0)
    {
        calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays + workingDays / 6 * 2;
    }
    else
    {
        calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays + workingDays / 7 * 2;
    }
```

Always put braces around your `if` statements. If not, horrible bugs may occur when you change your code:

For example, lets say you have this `if` statement:

```
if(isTrue())
    doSomething();
```

And you want to add `doSomething2()` to it. You do:

```
if(isTrue())
    doSomething();
    doSomething2();
```

Note that the code above would be equivalent to:

```
if(isTrue()) {
    doSomething();
}
doSomething2();
```

Which is probably not what you want. But if you put braces:

```
if(isTrue()) {
    doSomething();
    doSomething2();
}
```

Then it is fine.

---

```
    // ...  
    else
    {
        calculatedWorkingDays = workingDays + workingDays / 7 * 2;
    }



    HolidayList =  "Read the list from Json file";
    // ...
```

Don't put too much spaces in your code. It makes it look messier and harder to read.

---

```
        if (Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
```

The empty `if` can be easily avoided by doing:

```
        if (!(Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || Holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday))
        {
            // ...
        }
```

---

```
    foreach (DateTime d in SelectedHolidays)
        if (d.Date == date_OrderRequestedToShip.Date)
            calculatedWorkingDays++;
```

Again, braces:

```
    foreach (DateTime d in SelectedHolidays) {
        if (d.Date == date_OrderRequestedToShip.Date) {
            calculatedWorkingDays++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "`if` statement's braces should start on the same line (as a convention)" This is absolutely not true. Perhaps this is the convention at your place, but I've always written curly braces on a new line. **Consistency** is important, however: don't mix styles.

Comment: @BCdotWEB thanks for the point, I will remove that from my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Don't put the braces on the same line with the statement, ie:

```
if(...) {
}
```

do this instead:

```
if (...)
{
}
```

Why?
Putting the brace on the same line as the statement makes it harder to read the code and match the braces. Putting them on a separate improves your ability to read the code faster.
And every manager in the world want's you to code faster...

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you. You may want to [read about the formatting syntax](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help) before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Note that the OP already uses the style you recommend, so I don't see how this review is relevant. It looks like it's commenting on TheCoffeeCup's answer instead?