# Printing a BST tree level-by-level

Tags: java, tree

Please review and tell me what improvements can be made:

```
package trees;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class PrintBSTLevelByLevel {


     public static class Node {

        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node(int val){

            this.data = val;
            Node left = null;
            Node right = null;

        }
    }

      public void LevelOrderQueue(Node root){

          Queue q = new LinkedList();
          int levelNodes = 0;

          if(root == null) return;
          q.add(root);

          while(!q.isEmpty()){

              levelNodes = q.size();

              while (levelNodes > 0){

                  Node n = (Node)q.remove();
                  System.out.println(""+n.data);
                  if(n.left!= null)
                      q.add(n.left);
                  if(n.right!=null)
                      q.add(n.right);
                  levelNodes--;

              }
              System.out.println("");




          }



          //return null;
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node root = new Node(5);

        root.left = new Node(10);
        root.right = new Node(15);
        root.left.left = new Node(20);
        root.left.right = new Node(25);
        root.right.left = new Node(30);
        root.right.right = new Node(35);

        PrintBSTLevelByLevel l = new PrintBSTLevelByLevel();

        System.out.println(" Output by Better Approach : ");
        l.LevelOrderQueue(root);




    }




}
```

Comment: you should avoid using raw types the only reason they exist is because of backward compatibility. `Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();`

Comment: @MAG Thanks. Am I required to mention `node` inside the angel brackets for `LinkedList` as well ? Just like `LinkedList<Node>()`. Please clarify.

Comment: Also, writing `Node n = (Node)q.remove();` as `Node n = q.remove();` will also improve the code, am I right?

Comment: No for Java 7 or later the compiler is able to infer the type so you just need <>. Yes after using generics that cast is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your code would suffice for the current task, I would create a fully (or partially) functioning `Tree` class, so that it may be used later. Another class will handle the display. This is what the `Tree` class would look like:

```
public class Tree<T> {

    private Node rootNode;

    public Tree() {
        rootNode = null;
    }

    public Tree(T rootValue) {
        rootNode = new Node(rootValue);
    }

    public Node getRootNode() {
        return rootNode;
    }

    public Node createNewNode(T value) {
        return new Node(value);
    }

    class Node {

        private T value;
        public Node left = null;
        public Node right = null;

        Node(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

    }

}
```

This is an extremely basic `Tree` class that has very basic functions, but it gets the job done. Later, when you need more functions for the `Tree` class, you can easily go and add it. Explanation of the class:

- The default constructor (`Tree()`) will just set the root node to null.
- The other constructor will take the argument and create a new `Node` with the value of the argument.
- The `getRootNode()` method is to get the root `Node`, so that you can get the other `Node`s like so:

```
// example
Tree tree = new Tree(10);
// initialization of values
Node someNode = tree.getRootNode().left.right/*etc*/;
```

- The `createNewNode(T value)` method provides indirect access to the otherwise inaccessible (at least outside the package) `Node(T value)` constructor. Though this isn't necessary, as you can make the `Node`'s constructor public, it is good practice for later.
- The `Node` class is a simple class that represents a node with a left and right node, as well as its value:

  - The value is a `private` variable, so getters and setters are required to access it. Again, though you can just make `value` `public`, it is better practice not do so.
  - I made the `left` and `right` variables public, just for easier usage. Though it differs from good practice, there are some cases where there are exceptions (some programmers may disagree with this statement).

Now, for the printing component:

Since I redesigned the `Tree` class completely, we have to change your method as well. Just to do exactly what your code does, here is the new method:

```
public <T> void LevelOrderQueue(Tree<T> tree) {
    if (tree != null) {
        Tree<T>.Node rootNode = tree.getRootNode();
        if (rootNode != null) {
            Queue<Tree<T>.Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
            int levelNodes = 0;
            queue.add(rootNode);
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                levelNodes = queue.size();
                while (levelNodes > 0) {
                    Tree<T>.Node node = queue.remove();
                    System.out.println(node.getValue());
                    if (node.left != null) {
                        queue.add(node.left);
                    }
                    if (node.right != null) {
                        queue.add(node.right);
                    }
                    levelNodes--;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Note some changes:

- The method now takes a `Tree<T>` object instead of a `Node` object.
- This method has two checks for `null`; the first one to check for the tree, and the second one for the root node.
- I added braces for `if` statements. The reason for this is because the lack of braces may cause horrible, hard-to-spot bugs that might frustrate you for days. I can't find the post which I wrote about this in more detail, but I will post it up once I find it. (**EDIT**: Found it! Read [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83668/calculate-next-working-day/83671#83671))
- I added generics to your `Queue` initialization.
- I removed the `Node` cast. This is not necessary when generics are used.
- I changed naming. Variable names like `node` and `queue` are easier to understand than `n` and `q`.
- I changed `System.out.println("");` to `System.out.println();`. There is a `println()` method that takes no arguments.
- I changed `System.out.println(""+n.data);` to `System.out.println(node.value);`. The beginning `""` is not necessary because `System.out.println()` automatically converts what is given into a String, via the `toString()` method defined by the class (or whatever class before it in the inheritance chain that has it defined).
- I added more space between some individual keywords, variable names, braces, parentheses etc.: this is for better readability, and to follow the Java conventions. If you are not sure of them, just search up "Java Conventions" on [google](https://www.google.com/).
- I removed empty lines. You may re-add them where you like them; I like my code that way.